# SMARTS pattern for amines with connected carbons only having bonds to carbon or hydrogen

Tags: cheminformatics

I'm trying to find a SMARTS pattern that matches primary and secondary amines, where the connected carbon atoms only have connections to other carbon atoms or hydrogens (to exclude amides, guanidines, etc.)

It should match diethylamine, octylamine, t-butylamine or aniline, but not if any other heteroatom is connected to the amine's carbon(s), like in an amide, oxazolidine etc.

I could write a very long SMARTS pattern, where I include all the possible carbon/hydrogen connections that are possible for the carbons connected to the amine, something like this:

`[$([#7H2][CX4(C)(C)C, CX3H1(C)C, CX2H2C, CX1H3, CX3(C)C, ...]), $([#7H1][...]]`

Is there a shorter/better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for a nitrogen with three connections `NX3`

AND has 1 OR 2 hydrogen `;H1,H2`

AND is NOT connected to noncarbon `;!$(N[!#6])`

AND is NOT concected to a carbon that is NOT connected to carbon `;!$(N#6]~[!#6])`

`[NX3;H1,H2;!$(N[!#6]);!$(N[#6]~[!#6])]` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the detailed explanation! I tried this in rdkit and it almost works, except for aniline `C1=CC=C(C=C1)N`. I changed the SMARTS to `[NX3;H1,H2;!$(N[!#6]);!$(N[#6][!#6])]` to explicitly include any carbon, which works for aniline, but unfortunately this now also matches nicotinamide `C1=CC(=CN=C1)C(=O)N`, where the amide NH2 is matched. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: @snurden The change to `#6` was a good idea (I forgot aromatic carbon). The problem with nicotinamide is the double bonded oxygen. I changed the last pattern from single bond to any bond `~`. Hope it works now.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Totally forgot about the implicit single bond.